# MySQL - Finding if a User has taken a Course, and if so, which one, too many rows being generated

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm working on creating a `query` where I can see if certain users have taken a course, and if they have, what course did they take.

There are three tables that I'm using to get this information.

The first table is called `users` and is:

```
Users:
    uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR,
    email VARCHAR
```

The second table is `courses` and is:

```
Courses:
    cid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR,
    starts DATETIME,
    ends DATETIME
```

The third table is `UserCourses` and is:

```
UserCourses:
    cid INTEGER,
    uid INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(cid,uid),
    FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES Courses (cid),
    FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES Users (uid)
```

*NOTE*: There are many more fields in the `User` and `Courses` table, I'm only listing those relevant. I am working with a given database, so I can't make any changes to any tables.

Now, the thing is, there are only two different courses that are taught, but since each course is taught between a certain time period (span of 8 weeks), a row is created each time a course is added to the system and thus, given a unique `cid`.

There has been no naming convention of what these courses are called, but the courses are normally called `Course I` and `Course II`. But sometimes these courses are called `Course 1` and `Course 2` respectively.

What I am trying to do is that I'm trying to see if `users` have taken `courses` and if so, which course. I don't need the name of the course, just if they have taken `Course I` or `Course II`, just a `'Yes','No'` or just a Boolean `0 or 1`.

The SQL I've made to try and solve this is:

```
SELECT
    u.uid,
    IF(c1.name REGEXP 'Course I?$ | Course I[[:space:]] | Course 1','Yes','No') as 'Course 1',
    IF(c2.name REGEXP 'Course II$ | Course II[[:space:]] | Course 2','Yes','No') as 'Course 2'

FROM
    Users u,
    UserCourses uc

LEFT JOIN Courses c1
    ON uc.cid = c1.cid

LEFT JOIN Courses c2
    ON uc.cid = c2.cid

#WHERE u.uid = uc.cid  /This was edited out, @Richard spotted this error, see his answer
WHERE u.uid = uc.uid

ORDER BY u.uid
;
```

And when I run this I get each user and see if he has taken a particular course or not. But if the user has been enrolled in courses multiple times (but in each course with different `cid`), then I get a new row for each enrollment of the user.

What I'm trying to achieve is just get the `Yes` or `No` for columns `Course 1` and `Course 2`. I don't have to know if they took multiple courses on the same level (e.g. same user taking `Course I` three times), I just need to know if they have taken `Course 1` or not.

I tried using `GROUP BY u.uid` but it changes the fields in columns `Course 1` and `Course 2`.

Any information or a prod in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I've been pouring over SQL trying to find a solution but I feel like I hit a wall and I need someone to help me get over it to continue understanding what is going on here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines?

```
SELECT
    u.uid,
    MAX(IF(c.name REGEXP 'Course I?$ | Course I[[:space:]] | Course 1', 1, 0)) AS 'Course 1',
    MAX(IF(c.name REGEXP 'Course II$ | Course II[[:space:]] | Course 2', 1, 0)) AS 'Course 2'
FROM
    Users u
    INNER JOIN UserCourses uc ON uc.uid = u.uid
    LEFT JOIN Courses c ON c.cid = uc.cid
GROUP BY
    u.uid
ORDER BY 
    u.uid;
```

Comment: This is correct. Thank you!
There is one error in your answer that I noticed, on the `INNER JOIN`, where it says `uc.cid = u.uid` it should be `uc.uid = u.uid`.
When I did that, then it worked. Thank you again!
I would upvote your answer but I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: Cool, I fixed that.  I did wonder when I was writing the query but this is how the join worked in your original query (in the "old school" join in the WHERE clause).  Glad it worked out for you anyway :D

Comment: Bah! I see it now, I botched my original query! Thanks for pointing it out @Richard Hansell